# Python Cryptography Error ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency

Tags: virtualenv, pycrypto

In `cryptography` which was included using `pip install PyCrpto` giving an error after including it in a flask application where we are running it using virtual environment have named it **venv** and have this dependency correctly installed in `venv > lib > python2.7 > site-packages`.

Below is the exact error which I am getting here.

> **from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
>
>    ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency**

[image: from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency issue screenshot]

But as can be seen in screenshot file `cryptography.x509.certificate_transparency.py` is there in file structure and even on trying `python -c "from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency"` doesn't show any warnings but here it shows error which is also marked in red.

What can be possibly wrong here ?

Comment: How do you run flask? Does it use the **venv** environment?

Comment: Yes @phd flask is running inside venv

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when I was building an updated Python Crypto module for shipping with Solaris (see https://www.jmcpdotcom.com/blog/2018-02-21-im-embarrassed-to-admit-it/).

The root cause in your case appears to be that you haven't installed it in the right place. While you claim above that it's "correctly installed" in `venv > lib > python2.7 > site-packages` the screenshot shows that it is in fact in `venv/lib/cryptography`. If you move the cryptography dir down a level I would expect that your import would work.